# Connection Timeout on Windows Share (Network)

Tags: networking, samba, shared-folders

I have set up a shared drive on my office network, the shared drive is on a Windows 7 PC and I have connected to it on my Ubuntu 16.04 using the Network (Samba Share). I am able to use the share drive but after using it for some time, I am no longer able to access it, I keep getting an error message:

[image]

The Share folder works fine after restart,

How can I keep my connection from timing out?

Answer (score 15):

Had the same problem on Ubuntu 16.04.

Works for me after doing this quick fix:

1. Edit the samba conf file: `sudo gedit /etc/samba/smb.conf`
2. Then add this line in the [global] section `client max protocol = SMB3`